# Login android project into localhost server

Tags: json

This is my Code:

```
     public void CheckUserNameandPwd() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String  username = u.getText().toString().trim();
        String  pwd=pwdd.getText().toString().trim();
        if(username.length()==0){
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dlgAlert.setMessage("Fill UserName!");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Error");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();
            return;
        }
        else if(pwd.length()==0 ){
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dlgAlert.setMessage("Fill Password!");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("Error");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();
            return;
        }
        else{
            if(verifyLogin(username,pwd)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error occur!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,mainlayout_activity.class));
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean verifyLogin(St

ring username, String pwd) {
        try{
            showpDialog();
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget=new HttpGet("http://127.0.0.1:8083/MyService.svc/LoginForUsers?UserName=" + username + "&Password=" + pwd);
            HttpResponse httpresponse=httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity httpentity=httpresponse.getEntity();
            InputStream stream=httpentity.getContent();
            String result=ConvertStreamToString(stream);
            if(result.charAt(1)=='1'){
                hidepDialog();
                return  true;
            }else {
                hidepDialog();
                return  false;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            hidepDialog();
            return  false;

        }
    }

    private String ConvertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
       String line=null;
        try
        {
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return  sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: You are going to have to edit your question. Add 4 spaces on the first section cause we can't read anything...

Comment: Also, NEVER use login information on a get request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use a GET request to your server if you have a password on the url!!

Here's a POST request that may help you. Taken from [here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89)

```
     ...
     // Create data variable for sent values to server 

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;
     // Send data
      try
      {

          // Defined URL  where to send data
          URL url = new URL("http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/httppost.php");

       // Send POST data request

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write( data );
        wr.flush();

        // Get the server response

      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line = null;
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your sample code line,sir.
but i face this error when connect android client to asp.net IIS Server.
 
errorConnection to http://127.0.0.1:8083 refused
 
link of IIS server is:http://127.0.0.1:8083/MyService.svc/Login?UserName=admin&Password=ace
this link returns me "true" value.Sir.
why?help me plz...why i face connection refused error?sis.

Comment: Well, if you're on a mobile device, you cannot connect to "127.0.0.1" and expect to reach a different machine, since that number represents your local host. If you do that on a device, you're connecting to the device itself! So, you want to run your server and find its ip address. Then, other devices will be able to connect to that device via its ip. eg: 192.168.1.91:8083. Just make sure you server can be accessed from the outside world, but that it's a different issue. You might have to phisically input the ip of the machine when you start the server.

Comment: Before you do anything on a mobile, be sure that you're server is running and can be accessed from other computers in the local network. I just realized you're using windows server, right? I honestly don't know anything about windows server, but the principle is the same. Find the ip address, and se if you can access that server from another browser in your local network. If it's ok, you can start testing things on android.

Comment: yes,sir .i use IIS server on windows platform .my project is run with android emulator device not real phone .sir. i face connection refuse error when connect my localhost server :127.0.0.1:8083:/Myservice.svc/...